# Delayed timer bug in the comments section?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I am considering this a bug unless someone proves me wrong...

There seems to be a delay between the time a comment is posted and the actual time counter. In my case ( real one - just in case anybody thinks they faked - try it yourself ), there is a delay of about 1.5 minutes

I think the below screenshots are going to make it easier to see where it all comes from:

[image]

1. I am posting a comment at 11:02 to the question that has been asked 9 minutes ago
2. Its been a minute - the comment timer does not update
3. at 1.5 minute from the time I posted the comment the comment timer shows 29 sec - about one 1 minute delay
4. ss from the activity tab from my profile showing time posted the comment 11:03.

You should clearly now see the 1 minute gap/delay

Comment: I don't understand - your 4th screenshot is of something different. What exactly are you showing there?

Comment: Maybe your clock is not in sync with the server ones?

Comment: @Oded: The 4th screenshot calculates the comment as being posted at 11:03 (11.18 - 15), yet the first three screenshows show it was posted ~10:53 (11:02,3,4 - 9,10,11).

Comment: @Matt - Yeah. Took me a while to understand that the OP was now looking at their activity tab on their profile.

Comment: First question - is your local computer clock correct, to the minute?

Comment: It works for me with a few seconds delay - maybe caching.

Comment: Remember when your comment was 2min and 59 secs ago, it will show 2min in the profile.

Comment: @juergend I have checked the clocks, they are synchronised. But i cant see how that would affect the 1 minute delay anyways

Comment: even now, if i post a comment - the timer doesnt update til about 1 minute after the `add comment`s been clicked

Comment: the way SO displays the time is inconsistent. some 'places' in web source from the server timer where other use the local time of the user. thats where the mismatch is

Comment: We use a UTC timestamp. In some places we read that in JavaScript and using the local time display the relative time that passed. The user profile page is also cached for a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We update relative times once a minute, because doing it every second would be *extremely* annoying (and computationally wasteful).  As a result you may see +/- 60 sec times depending on where the interval falls when looking at a minute resolution, the behavior is intentional.